# Image upload to blob not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this html in the form

```
<input name="image" type="file" />
```

and this is in the php

```
$actorsex = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['ActorSex']);
$actoraccent = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['ActorAccent']);
$language = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['Language']);
$logo = addslashes(file_get_contents($connect, $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$aftereffects = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['AfterEffects']);

$sql="INSERT INTO orders (name, email, website, phone, companyname, productservice,                        voiceover, videowritten, targetcustomer, productsolve, featurebenefit, briefoutline,   productbenefit, videoideas, calltoaction, actorsex, actoraccent, language, logo,   aftereffects)
VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$website', '$phone', '$companyname', '$productservice', '$voiceover', '$videowritten', '$targetcustomer', '$productsolve', '$featurebenefit', '$briefoutline', '$productbenefit', '$videoideas', '$calltoaction', '$actorsex', '$actoraccent', '$language', '$logo', '$aftereffects')";
```

There is more obviously but I did not want to flood the screen. The image data is not passing to the database, yes the logo column is a mediumblob (I know this is not the golden way but its how I need it done for this project).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh I should add that everything else in the form works and passes as it should.

Comment: Is `enctype="multipart/form-data"` part of your form and using POST as the method? If it isn't, add it.

Comment: You're welcome Use `var_dump($_FILES);` then to see if anything comes of it. It's hard to say because we'd need to see just a bit more code to be sure. Check if all your variables check out and add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` if you're not already doing so.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  99 times out of 100, when a less experienced developer wants to add a file as blob to database, it is the wrong design decision.  There are really VERY few cases where one might want to do this (like you need to do a binary search against the blob data). Typically, a URL or link to a file's location on server is most appropriate for storage in the database.

Comment: This is what I get back with error reporting:     array(1) { ["image"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(19) "g2aheaderbanner.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpn2SNIJ" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(21089) } } Warning: file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /hermes/bosweb26b/b2309/ipg.ursiteup/actvidsale/purchase-handler.php on line 29 1 record added    Line 29 is the line with the $logo variable.

Comment: Because I am tracking the issue one step at a time, when I coded for that nothing worked so I went back to the most basic of code, and it seems that the $_FILES information is just not passing properly, if I can get that worked out I will go upward. You know it is not helpful to argue with people, it only delays the situation.

Comment: The "argue" part, I hope that wasn't aimed at me.

Comment: I imagine the "argue" comment was aimed at me.  It wasn't an argument, just a strong suggestion as to how you approach this problem. My guess is it will simplify things greatly for you, as it will reduce the amount of work your application server and database need to do, as well as allow for better client-side caching of the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you passing $connect ?

```
$logo = addslashes(file_get_contents($connect, $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
```

should be:

```
$logo = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
```

Have you considered storing the path to the image instead? If so you should mention why it is not a option.